# configure error c compiler cannot create executables server while installing python in remote server

Tags: server, python, remote-access

I tried to install python3 in remote server using

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-3.7.1.tgz
```

After that, I tried

```
  cd Python-3.7.1
  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

then I got the following error:

```
   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
  See `config.log' for more details
```

I am unable to solve this error. Please help me with this.

Comment: What does `config.log` say?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the contents of config.log.

Comment: Actually I am getting the following error : cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: So do you have space left?